# ActiveMQ "Classic" tuning for 20,000 threads

Tags: activemq-classic

I have running ActiveMQ which connects thru stomp port with 20,000+ servers at same time to publish and consume message. The ActiveMQ "Classic" server is running 8CPU and 32G memory. I have assigned JVM max memory as -Xmx16384m, but still when all the servers are connected the server gets over-loaded and Virtual Memory usage about 21G and CPU utilization is about 500 some times.

I'm not sure whether JVM uses that much or any other process utilizing in this ActiveMQ and tried with many tunings with no improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should reconsider the architecture. If you really need that many servers you may want to try a non blocking messaging bus, like [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/). I don't know for sure how many STOMP client it will support under your setup but it's worth a try. Keeping that many clients a separate threads will have a huge memory footprint and I think Artemis will handle such cases better. Not sure for STOMP though.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ 5.x can handle this given the proper Java VM tuning and activemq.xml configuration. However, it is generally advisable to partition this type of traffic with any type of distributed system. This is called a 'Gateway Architecture'.

Java VM tuning: gc tuning, -Xss reduction
ActiveMQ tuning: nio, disable dedicated task runner, etc.